# docker-machine in docker on server

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, docker-machine

I have a centos machine/server where I want to run multiple instances of docker containers with them having docker-machines with virtualbox driver inside them for testing purposes. Is it even doable?

I have a docker image from latest centos7. I then run

```
sudo docker run --privileged -ti test
```

Inside the docker container I installed docker, docker-machine and virtualbox.

```
docker-machine --version
docker-machine version 0.10.0

VBoxManage --version 
5.1.16r113841

docker --version
Docker version 17.03.0-ce
```

When I run

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

I get the following error

```
(default) Creating a new host-only adapter produced an error: /usr/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif create failed:
(default) 0%...
(default) Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
(default) VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
(default) VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
(default) VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
(default) VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
(default)
(default) This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue
The default lines below are for a sh/bash shell, you can specify the shell you're using, with the --shell flag.
```

Does anybody know how I could get around this issue? My virtualbox already is newer than the stated 5.0.12 version.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of uninstall>reinstalls it started working...